# NPM - How do I override one of my dependencies dependency?

Tags: npm, dependencies, package.json, shrinkwrap, package-lock.json

Recently, npm released the [npm audit](https://docs.npmjs.com/getting-started/running-a-security-audit) command. It runs automatically when you `npm i` letting you know of any vulnerabilities. I have a simple dependency tree, something like this:

```
package A
package B
  package B dependency
package C
```

My `package.json` includes A, B, and C in the `dependencies` field. B is requiring its own dependency, which npm warns has vulnerabilities. My question is, how can I override the `package B dependency` version so as to use the latest version?  I've read around that this is either the job for `shrinkwrap.json` or manually editing `package-lock.json` but I can't find any concrete examples showing how to do it.

I *did* see that Yarn supports a `resolutions` field in `package.json`, but I'm not using Yarn. Is there a way to accomplish this with npm out of the box?